# How to know which div called a function in a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got six divs that act as buttons. When clicked, one of the spans in a different div (and class) is displayed, and others are hidden.

Buttons:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menubutton">
        Menu1
    </div>
      .
      .
      .
    <div class="menubutton">
        Menu6
    </div>
</div>
```

Info shown based on clicked button:

```
<div class="information">
    <span class="information1"> Info1 </span>
    ...
    <span class="information6"> Info6 </span>
</div>
```

How do I know which one called the function, so I can know which span to make visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided your markup is this way:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menubutton">
        Menu1
    </div>
     <div class="menubutton">
        Menu2
    </div>
     <div class="menubutton">
        Menu3
    </div>
     <div class="menubutton">
        Menu4
    </div>
     <div class="menubutton">
        Menu5
    </div>
    <div class="menubutton">
        Menu6
    </div>
</div>
<div class="information">
    <span class="information1"> information1 </span>
    <span class="information2"> information2 </span>
    <span class="information3"> information3 </span>
    <span class="information4"> information4 </span>
    <span class="information5"> information5 </span>
    <span class="information6"> information6 </span>
</div>
```

You can do this:

```
$('.menubutton').click(function(){
     var index = $('.menubutton').index(this); //get the index of the menubutton clicked
    $('.information > span').eq(index).show().siblings().hide(); // show the corresponding information item based onthe clicked one's index and hide others.
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tebWt/)**

with this you can safely remove the class with index like `information1, information2` etc instead you can add a common class say `content`

```
 <div class="information">
        <span class="content"> information1 </span>
        <span class="content"> information2 </span>
        <span class="content"> information3 </span>
        <span class="content"> information4 </span>
        <span class="content"> information5 </span>
        <span class="content"> information6 </span>
    </div>
```

and change it to:

```
$('.menubutton').click(function(){
         var index = $('.menubutton').index(this); //get the index of the menubutton clicked
        $('.information > .content').eq(index).show().siblings().hide(); // show the corresponding information item based onthe clicked one's index and hide others.
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't have ID's, we can get the index of the clicked menu item, add 1, then find the corresponding `information` span to show:

```
$(".menubutton").click(function() {
    var menuIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(".information" + menuIndex).show();
});
```

Comment: I can't assign ID's, and I'd like to do it without assigning different classes if possible.

Comment: Hmm... well, give me a few mins, I'm fashioning a nice answer :)

Comment: Didn't know about `.index()`, that's exactly what I needed. Works. I'd like to know why I have to add `1`, though.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović -- Index's are 0 based, so the menu1 item has an index of 0, but your information spans start at 1, so I added 1.

Comment: Why don't information spans start at `0` as well then? Or it's "just the way it is"... :)

Comment: Oh dumb me. I get it now, it's my class names. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The this keyword inside a function refers to the element that called the function.

Comment: However, when I traverse though other div's, I lose the fact that, for example, second div was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `#id` for each `menubutton`, so:

```
<div class="menubutton" id="btn_1"></div>
```

then:

```
$(".menubutton").on("click", function() {
  // Get the id of button clicked.
  var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];

  // Target SPAN with the same id.
  $("SPAN.information" + id).show();
});
```

Comment: I can't add IDs since I will have lots of these sets of buttons. I'd like to navigate thourgh HTML (traverse) with jQuery somehow.

Comment: Ah, then as the first answer suggest, use the `.index()` of clicked button. Always have fun!